# generate single random number in a view in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, arc4random

i was playing around with an idea. in a single lable in a view when the view appears a random number is displayed. presently i have aview,  a lable and a button. press button random number is generated and the lables title is replaced with a random number....random number displayed.

what i wish to acheive is that there is no button, just a view and a text lable and when the view appears a random number is displayed also instantaneously with out the need for a button to prompt generation.
 here isi the code i have so far

```
#import "Mainview.h"

@implementation Mainview
- (IBAction)pushstart {

    NSString *title = nil;
    NSString *path = nil;

    int Number = arc4random() % 12;
    switch(Number) {
                    case 0:
                    namel.text = @"1";

                    break;
          case 1:
                    namel.text = @"2";

            break;

        case 2:
                    namel.text = @"3";

                    break;

        case 3:
                    namel.text = @"4";

                    break;

        case 4:
                    namel.text = @"5";

                    break;
        case 5:
            namel.text = @"6";

            break;

        case 6:
            namel.text = @"7";

            break;

        case 7:
            namel.text = @"8";

            break;

        case 8:
            namel.text = @"9";

            break;



        case 9:
            namel.text = @"10";

            break;

        case 10:
            namel.text = @"11";

            break;

        case 11:
            namel.text = @"12";

            break;


                            break;
                    default:
                    break;
    }


}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way shorter answer, this method goes in whatever class is controlling the view (same place as the current action method):

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    srandom(time(NULL));
    [namel setIntValue: random %12];
}
```

Comment: Or use arc4random().  No need to seed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arc4random_uniform` to generate the random number.

```
- (IBAction)pushstart {

namel.text = arc4random_uniform(12) + 1

}
```

Hope this can help.